# String xticks overlapping and TypeError in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, typeerror

I am trying to create a graph with a complete dataframe column as the x-ticks. However, all xticks are overlapping and not roated and I am receiving a TypeError (see image).

```
plot = results_df.plot(x='CPV Description', y=['Coefficient', 'Std Error'], figsize=(20,5), grid=False)
plot.set_ylabel('Coefficient/Std Error')
plot.set_xticklabels(results_df['CPV Description'])
plt.xticks(results_df['CPV Description'],rotation=90)
```

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: `plot` instead of `plt` maybe?

Comment: not working - AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'xticks'

Comment: Maybe scrap `results_df.plot` entirely and use `plt`? This seems helpful: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/ticks_and_spines/ticklabels_rotation.html#sphx-glr-gallery-ticks-and-spines-ticklabels-rotation-py

Comment: The problem is that you do not tell matplotlib *where* to put the labels. It should work though if you remove the last two lines. Rotating labels can e.g. be achieved through `plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)`.